Access clipboard contents from the command line
I want to explore rather than access the contents of the pasteboard/clipboard from the command line interface. I want to know whether there's something in it or what is in it.
For instance, if there's a photo I would like to get some info similar to what using Finder > Edit > Show Clipboard does. It even renders images and display some info.

Is there a command I can use to achieve a similar result (minus rendering)?
I have tried pbpaste, xclip and xsel but these won't do anything when the clipboard holds an actual image (binary).
In a way, I want the opposite of How to use terminal to copy a file to the clipboard?

Can you explain why you need it on the command line? Are you planning to further process the information in some way?

In my case, I am debugging an app which exports PNGs to the clipboard. Instead, it was copying something, but not a PNG. The clipboard was reporting is as a URL, but pasting it into a browser resulted in pasting nothing. I was hoping that CLI commands would provide more info as to what was in the clipboard. If this is useful information I will add it to the question.

As you can see from my example, even a PDF on the clipboard has an associated URL, which isn't a "browser" URL, but some kind of reference for the data.

Indeed, thank you, I tested yours on the aforementioned PNG image and it worked as expected.

You can query the Pasteboard manager using a script in Swift:
import AppKit
let board = NSPasteboard.general
print(board.types!)

Obviously, Swift will freak out if the result is empty.
If you've got python3 with pyobjc library installed, you can do:
from AppKit import NSPasteboard
board = NSPasteboard.generalPasteboard()
print(board.types())

The output from python is a bit neater and easier to deal with; though both are human readable. The results are an array of available file types.
Here's a python output for a PDF copied to the pasteboard, which contains PDF, TIFF, and text.
(
    "com.adobe.pdf",
    "Apple PDF pasteboard type",
    "public.tiff",
    "NeXT TIFF v4.0 pasteboard type",
    "dyn.ah62d4rv4gu8y6y4grf0gn5xbrzw1gydcr7u1e3cytf2gn",
    NSFilenamesPboardType,
    "public.file-url",
    "CorePasteboardFlavorType 0x6675726C",
    "dyn.ah62d4rv4gu8yc6durvwwaznwmuuha2pxsvw0e55bsmwca7d3sbwu",
    "Apple URL pasteboard type",
    "public.utf8-plain-text",
    NSStringPboardType
)


Perhaps more than I bargained but it definitely solves the problem!

It's not clear exactly what you want, but I'll assume you want to know what kind of content is in the Clipboard: text, image, or whatever.
You would have to paste into a temporary file and analyze that file:
pbpaste > temp
file -b temp
rm temp


When the contents of the clipboard is a PNG image pbpaste does nothing, and does so silently. How can I improve the question?

I imagine it was with redirection. Correction to my own comment. It creates an empty file, which is consistent with the original problem.
